# Is a work permit for Canada the same as a visa?

Tags: visas, canada

My girlfriend is from Sweden and is coming to Canada with me in September. She has already applied for and received her work permit. When I go onto the Canadian government website, it's very confusing and I can't figure out if she needs anything else.

Question: Is a work permit enough to travel/arrive into Canada and stay for at least a year and work…? Or will she need to get a visitors visa (or anything else) as well?

Comment: Good question, but belongs to [Expats.SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't think so - the expat part is already done, he's wondering if she needs a tourist visa.

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/visa-for-a-phd-and-ta-in-canada-for-swiss-citizens

Comment: @MarkMayo _"Question: Is a work permit enough to travel/arrive into canada and **stay for at least a year and work**"_

Comment: Ah see I was focusing on the fact that she has a work permit, but now wants to know if a visitor's visa is required - as explained in the preamble before that.  My answer covers that too.  If it's about the work permit itself, then yeah, expats is better, as I've explained in comments below as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The work permit allows you to live and work in Canada, on a temporary basis.  The requirements for such are on the [Work Permit page](http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca/eng/goc/work_permits.shtml) online.

Note the requirements are above and beyond having just the work permit - you need proof she is only visiting temporarily, for example.

However, once you have a work permit, that works as a visa - you don't need an additional tourist visa to enter the country.

Comment: Do you know how long "temporary" is? Or should I just ask that is a whole separate question…just wondering now how long she can stay for...

Comment: That's definitely more of an [Expats](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) question, sorry, I don't know the answer offhand if it's not already on the visa.

Comment: @Jake The expiration date is noted on the work permit itself.

Comment: @200_success
It doesn't have an expiration date listed…

But it does say the following:
IMPORTANT: Regulations have established a maximum cumulative duration of four years that a Temporary
Foreign Worker can work in Canada. After four years of work has been accumulated, a period of 48 months
spent not working in Canada must elapse before another work permit can be issued, with some limited
exceptions.

Does that mean she can stay for 4 years? Seems like a long time for a work visa...